# How many types of gesture does IOS Support

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uigesturerecognizer

How many type of gesture that ios can recognize and we can work on occurring that gesture.

Language Swift / Objective C
Platform Xcode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically it comes down to Gesture Recogniser types which are:

> Tapping (any number of taps) - *UITapGestureRecognizer*
>
> Pinching in and out (for zooming a view) - *UIPinchGestureRecognizer*
>
> Panning or dragging - *UIPanGestureRecognizer*
>
> Swiping (in any direction) - *UISwipeGestureRecognizer*
>
> Rotating (fingers moving in opposite directions) -
>   *UIRotationGestureRecognizer*
>
> Long press (also known as “touch and hold”) -
>   *UILongPressGestureRecognizer*

If this isn't what you need you can create a subclass of UIGestureRecognize and come up with your own solution. You can find everything you need on this topic in Apple [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizer_basics/GestureRecognizer_basics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH2-SW2).

Since iOS 9 there's a "Peek an Pop" action aka hard press aka 3D touch - some might consider this a gesture too, but it's a little bit more complicated. You can find some info [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/Adopting3DTouchOniPhone/).

Answer (score 4):

There are seven type of `gesture` that support in `ios`.

- Tap Gesture Recognizer
- Pinch Gesture Recognizer
- Rotation Gesture Recognizer
- Swipe Gesture Recognizer
- Pan Gesture Recognizer
- Screen Edge Pan Gesture Recognizer
- Long Press

Comment: Can we create our own gesture ?